# MDX Calculated member of 2 set

Tags: mdx

If I have a `[USER]` dimension, and 2 hierarchies, `FIRST NAME` and `LAST NAME`. How can I create a calculated Member of `FULL NAME` of these two hierarchies` values?

Comment: what client are you using to extract data from your cube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**BUT** this would be much better if added to your warehouse dimension and added to the cube as a new hierarchy

An example of joining up member_caption properties:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[JOINEDUP] AS 
      [Customer].[Customer].CurrentMember.Member_Caption + ' '
    + 
      [Customer].[Gender].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[JOINEDUP]} ON 0
 ,
  [Customer].[Customer].[Customer] * [Customer].[Gender].[Gender] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Results of the above:

[image]

Here is an `icCube` example:

```
 With
  Member MyOutput AS [Date Dim.Weekday Hierarchy].[Weekday].name + " " + [Time Dimension.Time Hierarchy].[Hour] + " " + STR( ([Measures].[Page Views]) )
 SELECT 
  NON EMPTY {[Measures].[MyOutput]} ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY {
    Crossjoin({[Date Dim.Weekday Hierarchy].[Weekday].Members}, 
          {[Time Dimension.Time Hierarchy].[Hour].Members})
      } ON ROWS
  FROM [All Facts]
```

Comment: Error:No function matches signature '<String> + <String>'

Comment: my script does not error - it is against AdvWrks deliberately so I can test it.

Comment: @István  Instead of '+', use '||'